# Распарсить массив

Tags: массивы, php

`$get_operations = $resp->getOperations();` выдаёт следующий массив:

```
object(YM_Operation)#7 (6) {
  ["operationId":protected]=>
  string(18) "435067597580030004"
  ["patternId":protected]=>
  string(3) "p2p"
  ["direction":protected]=>
  string(3) "out"
  ["amount":protected]=>
  float(17.09)
  ["datetime":protected]=>
  int(1381752408)
  ["title":protected]=>
  string(30) "Перевод для modal456"
}
```

Как мне получить например **operationId**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не массив, а объект класса YM_Operation, поля, судя по дампу, непосредственно не доступны (protected), поищите в исходниках этот класс, теоретически в нем должны быть getter'ы для доступа к этим полям.

Comment: @inso, а как например к ним обратиться? :/